# CommandException: arg [...] does not name a directory, bucket, or bucket subdir. for a directory on Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google, gsutil

I am trying to use gsutils command to deploy changes from CircleCI to a directory on my Compute Engine instance. The command I am using is:
`gsutil -m rsync -d -r dev/ [VM_INSTANCE_NAME]:/var/www/dev/`

but I get the following error:

`CommandException: arg [...] does not name a directory, bucket, or bucket subdir.`

Based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync), I should be able to deploy to the directory on Compute Engine.

Comment: the gsutil it's tool to interact between Google cloud storage and the GCP, I'm not sure if it's possible with the CircleCI, first you need to have the Google SDK installed in the destination or the source to interact with google storage. normally the google stroage always begin with gs://gs://your-bucket/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alioua is correct. I understand where you're trying to refer to the document but that would only work if it the directories were local. If you're using CircleCI, you'd be better off using a service account and assign it the correct IAM permissions.

Although a normal `rsync` would work, you could also use `gcloud compute scp` or `gcloud compute copy-files`. `gsutil rsync` would only work with buckets or 'across local directories'.